# How to group and filter by 2 columns?

Tags: pandas

Imagine the following dataset that represents owners of Restaurants and Bars in USA and UK:

```
   Owner  Property    Country
0  John   Restaurant  UK
1  John   Bar         USA
2  George Bar         USA  
3  George Restaurant  USA
```

How can I find the owners that have both types of properties in the same country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), compare by `2` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 =  df[df.groupby(['Owner', 'Country'])['Property'].transform('nunique').eq(2)]
print (df1)
    Owner    Property Country
2  George         Bar     USA
3  George  Restaurant     USA
```